# Replace space between two words with an underscore in a vector

Tags: r

I have words, Genus species, and I want an underscore to replace the space between the two strings in R

Input:

```
>data$species
Genus species
```

Desired output:

```
>data$species
Genus_species
```

Comment: use `data$species <- sub(" ", "_", data$species)`

Answer (score 25):

We can use `sub` from `base R`

```
data$species <- sub(" ", "_", data$species)
```

Or with `chartr` from `base R`

```
data$species <- chartr(" ", "_", data$species)
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
    mutate(species = str_replace(species, " ", "_"))
```

Comment: If you want to replace only the first "space" in the string, use sub. But if you want all the "space" replaced in the strings, use `gsub` . Answer also provided by @gaut , below this answer.

Comment: @CorinaRoca `g`sub is global substitution, thus it replace all the spaces with `_`

Answer (score 14):

You should use `gsub`:

```
data$species <- gsub(" ", "_", data$species)
```

Answer (score 5):

The pattern `[^[:alnum:]]` can be used to replace all non alphanumeric characters by underscores. Combine it with `tolower()` to convert all characters to snake case following the [tidyverse syntax recommendations](https://style.tidyverse.org/syntax.html).

```
column_names <- c("Bla Bla", "Hips / Hops", "weight (1000 kg)")
gsub("[^[:alnum:]]", "_", tolower(column_names))

[1] "bla_bla"          "hips___hops"      "weight__1000_kg_"
```

The pattern `[^[:alnum:]]+` replaces one or more occurrences by an underscore.

```
gsub("[^[:alnum:]]+","_",tolower(column_names))

[1] "bla_bla"         "hips_hops"       "weight_1000_kg_"
```

See `help(regexp)` for more information on regular expressions.