# In R, how to replace the space in column names with underscore for all columns?

Tags: r, parse-platform

I saw solutions using sql, but is there R code handling the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace space between two words with an underscore in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53107014/replace-space-between-two-words-with-an-underscore-in-a-vector)

Answer (score 3):

Supposing your columns are in "dataTable":

```
colnames(dataTable) = gsub(" ", "_", colnames(dataTable))
```